# ways to express something is too precious for one to use

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

Something like this wine is too precious to drink by myself now, I need to save for later.

Water is too precious in the desert, I need to save it for my children.

Comment: The sentences you’ve suggested communicate your intent well.

Comment: I can guess what you want, but I do not actually see it : What exactly is the question ? Currently, it looks like a statement about "ways to express" and 2 correct examples. If you can rephrase it like "How can I ..... ?" and give examples with missing words or phrases, it might help to respond to your core query. In the meanwhile, you can consider using https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/precious to get alternative words.